# /usr/bin/env: bash: Permission denied

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Suddenly, when your Seniors Linux Server admin does not come at office. And Then Junior Linux Admin take a charge of it, then it is NIGHTMARE for them. Please help.

I'm not able to recollect, that what I did in `.bashrc` file in the server, after re-logging in the server. Not a Single was not working. Commands like `ls`, `cat`, and `vi` was not working on the server. I was Getting Error: "Command not found".

I have manage to fix from below steps:

1. Edited `.bashrc` file in home pasted below text in the file

   `PATH=$PATH:/home/amol/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

   `export PATH`
2. After reloading `.bashrc` from command --> source `~/.bashrc`. Comands started working.

But  whenever I loggin in the server. I get below error:

```
Last login: Tue May 14 10:33:46 2013 from 14.140.90.22
/usr/bin/env: bash: Permission denied
/usr/bin/env: bash: Permission denied
/usr/bin/env: bash: Permission denied
/usr/bin/env: bash: Permission denied
/usr/bin/env: bash: Permission denied
-bash: tar: command not found
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
```

I have searched in Google, but not getting exact solution.

OS: Ubuntu 10.04.

Below is `.bashrc` file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5664287/

Please Help.

Comment: As what user do you connect to the server? Whose .bashrc have you edited?

Comment: Usually "Permission denied" happens when you don't have access to something, in this case probably the file `/usr/bin/env`.
I suggest you try running that as root and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is more likely in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (whichever happens to exist). PATH should not be set in `~/.bashrc`, it should be set in one of those profile files, and they should in turn source `~/.bashrc`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Answer (score 2):

I found [these](http://penguinparens.blogspot.com/2009/02/howto-not-get-usrbinenv-bad-interpreter.html) in penguinparens.blogspot.com:

> The partition your script lives on may be mounted with the "user" option set. "user" implies "noexec" (see the manpage for "mount"),
>   which is going to keep you from running executables. And while running
>   a binary executable from this kind of partition fails more clearly,
>   trying to run a script with a shebang gives you this more confusing
>   error message.
>
> To fix! Add "exec" after your "user" flag in /etc/fstab. (again, see
>   "man mount").

Answer (score 1):

With this much fudge, I'd strongly consider starting a new bashrc. Even without a correct `$PATH`, the following should work:

```
/bin/mv ~/.bashrc{,.BAK}
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Of course, depending on how messed up things are, you might need to replace `~` with the path to your home. Try it and see.

You'll need to run `/usr/bin/reset` which should reload your bash session. Otherwise, start a new one.